# Firebug throws up permission issue in Wordpress / timely calendar

Tags: ajax, wordpress, permissions, calendar, http-status-code-403

The Calendar on http://www.cpwacademy.org.uk/booking keeps hanging when trying to change months/tags/ etcetera. Strangely it does not hang when you are logged into wordpress.

Running firebug (when logged out of WP) it throws up the following error message when trying to go to the next month:

"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://www.cpwacademy.org.uk/booking/action~month/exact_date~1417440328/?request_type=json&ai1ec_doing_ajax=true"

Clearly there is a permission error, however i can not find a solution (even changing permissions on server did not work)
To reiterate, all works fine when logged in to WP and the above eror only occurs when logged out, ie like every visitor.

Hope this solution is an easy one and i am just overlooking the obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solution Found!

Was using Ithemes security plugin:

By unticking
* Suspicious Query Strings
* Filter out non-english characters from the query string.
In the plugins settings page

Everything started working again!